# html input not receiving barcode scanned data in electron app after production

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, barcode-scanner

there I am facing a problem with **barcode** scanned data. I am creating an app where I need to get **barcode scanned data into an HTML input element**. The app **works in development** and the HTML input receive data from the barcode **but in production, the HTML input does not receive data.**

**NOTE: i am using [barcode to pc app](https://barcodetopc.com/) for testing.**

here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<input  name="barcode-data" class="barcode-data-input">
```

**JS**

```
const barcodeInput = document.querySelector('.barcode-data-input');
  
  barcodeInput.focus();
  let keyBreakTimer = null;

  const notAllowedChars = [27, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 44, 19, 145, 45, 36, 33, 34, 35, 46, 144, 91, 16, 9, 20, 17, 18, 93, 8, 37, 39, 38, 40];

  //maximum allowed duration between input change or keypress.
  const keyWaitDuration = 500;

  barcodeInput.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (notAllowedChars.indexOf(e.keyCode) > 0) {
      console.log('not allowed');
      return;
    }
    clearTimeout(keyBreakTimer);

    keyBreakTimer = setTimeout(generateQRCode, keyWaitDuration);

  });


  barcodeInput.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    //check if user pressed any functional key
    if (notAllowedChars.indexOf(e.keyCode) > 0) {
      console.log('not allowed');
      return;
    }
    clearTimeout(keyBreakTimer);
  });
```

Comment: barcode scanners act as keyboard , so the code is ok (nothing specific is different for the scanner), you should check whats wrong on the production (maybe cache or not uploaded asset ) , check console and share if there are some usefull error logs.

Comment: This is an electron app. I checked the console multiple times in production but it's clear. The electron app does not detect the barcode scanner in production.

Comment: i also check the barcode reader with another electron app that i had developed earlier but the same problem.

Comment: As @John said, barcode readers are just keyboards as far as most apps are concerned. Does your electron app work when you use a regular keyboard to enter the barcode? Does the barcode reader work with non-electron apps?

Comment: Yeah when i use regular keyboard and it's also working with vscode which is made with electron. And it's also working with non electron app like notepad etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a nightmare of not having a solution to the problem above . But the problem was not with the electron itself.
The app "Barcode to PC" was a problem and the problem solved by just running the "Barcode to PC" as administrator.